# Parsing RDF items

Tags: java, scala, rdf

I have a couple lines of (I think) RDF data

```
<http://www.test.com/meta#0001> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> 
<http://www.test.com/meta#0002> <http://www.test.com/meta#CONCEPT_hasType> "BEAR"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

Each line has 3 items in it. I want to pull out the item before and after the URL. So that would result in:

```
0001, type, Class
0002, CONCEPT_hasType, (BEAR, string)
```

Is there a library out there (java or scala) that would do this split for me? Or do I just need to shove string.splits and assumptions in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most RDF libraries will have something to facilitate this. For example, if you parse your RDF data using [Eclipse RDF4J](http://rdf4j.org/)'s [Rio parser](http://docs.rdf4j.org/programming/#_parsing_and_writing_rdf_with_rio), you will get back each line as a `org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Statement`, with a subject, predicate and object value. The subject in both your lines will be an `org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI`, which has a `getLocalName()` method you can use to get the part behind the last #. See the [Javadocs](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/) for more details.

Assuming your data is in N-Triples syntax (which it seems to be given the example you showed us), here's a simple bit of code that does this and prints it out to STDOUT:

```
  // parse the file into a Model object
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/rdf-data.nt"));
  org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Model model = Rio.parse(in, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);

  for (org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Statement st: model) {
       org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Resource subject = st.getSubject();
       if (subject instanceof org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI) {
              System.out.print(((IRI)subject).getLocalName());
       }
       else {
              System.out.print(subject.stringValue());
       }
       // ... etc for predicate and object (the 2nd and 3rd elements in each RDF statement)
  }
```

*Update* if you don't want to read data from a file but simply use a `String`, you could just use a `java.io.StringReader` instead of an `InputStream`:

```
 StringReader r = new StringReader("<http://www.test.com/meta#0001> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> .");
 org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Model model = Rio.parse(r, RDFFormat.NTRIPLES);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to parse the data at all and just want to do String processing, there is a [org.eclipse.rdf4j.model,URIUtil](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/index.html?org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/util/URIUtil.html) class which you can just feed a string and it can give you back the index of the local name part:

```
  String uri = "http://www.test.com/meta#0001";
  String localpart = uri.substring(URIUtil.getLocalNameIndex(uri));  // will be "0001"
```

(disclosure: I am on the RDF4J development team)

Comment: What if I have a single RDF line and I want to split it up into an array of the 3 elements?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a single RDF line", RDF is a data model, not a syntax. What you have is a single line in N-Triples syntax. So, either use an N-Triples parser, which gives you a Statement, and then create your string array out of that, or just try and a do `String.split` on the line, followed by using e.g. URIUtil to get the localnames.